# Decode a value in django template

Tags: django

I am trying to decode a value from byte string in django-template. I have tried with **field|stringformat :'i'**, but it won't work.

Ex:- django template
`{{ pk:field }}`

The **field** value returns like this
`{'pk': b'122'}`

I need to get the value like `{'pk':122}`

Comment: Give an example or part of your code to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: After execution of this statement ```<a href = "{% url 'specdb:specdata_download' pk=field %}">```,  django raises the error as  ```Reverse for 'specdata_download' with keyword arguments '{'pk': b'122'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['specdb/download/(?P<pk>\\d+)']```

Comment: try this instead `"{% url 'specdb:specdata_download' field %}"`

Comment: You have to create a new template tag for your custom needs. Please refers to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, i have created custom module and importing into the template.  This how fixed.

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def convert_byte_to_string(value):
    return value.decode("utf-8") if value else value
```

In template i have mentioned as below.

```
field|convert_byte_to_string
```